# element.classList.contains() eaquals to undefined. Why?

Tags: javascript

Code below displays undefined:

```
function search(){
    let clas = document.querySelector('input#search').value;
    if(clas=="Speed"){
        clas="v";
    }else if(clas=="Dro"){
        clas="s";
    }else if(clas=="Cza"){
        clas="t";
    }else if(clas=="Przys"){
        clas="a";
    }
    find(clas);
}
function find(clas="*"){
        const elements = document.querySelector("main").childNodes;
        if(clas!="*"){
            console.log(elements[0].classList.contains("v"));
        }
}
```

I wanted to check if elements of main contain class "v" but my every attempt concludes with an error:

> script.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'contains')
> at find (script.js:17)
> at search (script.js:12)
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (calculator.html:18) find @ script.js:17 search @ script.js:12 onclick @ calculator.html:18

Main contains elements! I do not understand what I've done wrong and how to fix it. Could someone explain and help?

Comment: _"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'contains')"_ - You try to read/access the property `contains` from something that is `undefined` (it's not that `.contains()` is `undefined` as mentioned in the title)

Comment: the element probably has no classes at all - could be just a text, not a dom element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that you're trying to use `contains` on the value `undefined`. That tells us that the first child node of the `main` element is not an element (perhaps it's a text or comment node; often it's a text node with whitespace). Only element nodes have `classList`. So `elements[0].classList` is `undefined`.

You may have wanted [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) rather than [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes), if you wanted only *element* children.

Here's an example of the difference:

```js
const main = document.querySelector("main");
console.log("childNodes[0].nodeName:", main.childNodes[0].nodeName);
console.log("children[0].nodeName:", main.children[0].nodeName);
```

```html
<main>
    <p>Hi there</p>
</main>
```

Or if you're only going to use the first one, you could use [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/firstElementChild) instead of `children[0]`.

Comment: You were right, I did use comments and as it appears that was the problem. The ultimate solution is:  function find(clas='*'){
    const elements = document.querySelector("main").children;
    if(clas!="*"){
        for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if(elements[i].classList==undefined){
                console.log("un!");
            }
            if(elements[i].classList.contains("v")){
                elements[i].style.display="flex";
            }else{
                elements[i].style.display="none";
            }
        }
    }else{

    }
}